# How to calculate the gradient function of the logistic regression's cost function by using the directional derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, logistic-regression

Let's assume we have a dataset $\Omega = \{ (x^k, y^k) \in \mathbb{R}^p \times \{0,1\} | 1 \leq k \leq n \}$. I would like to compute the gradient of the logistic regression's cost function by using the notion of directional derivative.

Let be $E(\omega) = -\sum_{k=1}^n y^k \log(\sigma(x^k \omega)) + (1-y^k)\log(1 - \sigma(x^k \omega))$. Given a vector $d$, we define the directional derivative as :
$$ D(E,d) = \lim_{t \mapsto 0} \frac{E(\omega + td) - E(\omega)}{t} = \lim_{t \mapsto 0} \Delta_t(E,d) $$

Let be $t > 0$, we have :
$$  \log(\sigma(x^k \omega)) =  - \log(1+ e^{-x^k \omega}) $$
$$  \log(1 - \sigma(x^k \omega)) =  - x^k \omega - \log(1+ e^{-x^k \omega}) $$
Hence, 
$$ E(\omega) = \sum_{k=1}^n (1-y^k)u^k\omega + \log(1+ e^{-x^k \omega}) $$
Now, when I try to calculate the directional derivative, I get :
$$ \Delta_t(E, d) = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{k=1}^n (1-y^k)tx^k d + \log\frac{1+e^{-x^k(\omega + td)}}{1+e^{-x^k\omega}} $$
And I do not know how to get the following result :
$$ D(E,d) = < \nabla(E) | d > $$
I think I did something wrong, so would you like to help me :) ?
It would be great !
Many thanks,

Comment: $\sigma$ is the logistic function, i.e. $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

Comment: It made sense after I posted my comment, my mistake

Comment: After reading your post, I'm not sure what the trouble is you're having. Have you actually computed the limit as $t\to 0$ yet? Have you computed the gradient yet?

Comment: No, this is all what I have calculated until now. I have no idea how to computed the limit as $t\mapsto 0$.

Comment: First thing you should do is move the $t$ into the summation. Do you see any simplifications?

Comment: Well, I get :$ \sum_{k=1}^n (1-y^k)x^kd + \frac{1}{ŧ} \log \frac{1 + e^{-x^k(\omega+td)}}{1+e^{x^k\omega}}$ but I have no idea with that logarithm...

Comment: Well there are many things you can do. Are you more comfortable with L'Hopital or Taylor series?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102106/discussion-between-mistapopo-and-ninad-munshi).